# How to Refresh single column in Kendo UI Grid asp.net mvc?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, grid, refresh

Here is my code for loading data into Kendo Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.CountryName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CountryCode);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CountryCodeLength);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CurrencyString);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CountryISOName);
    })
    .Pageable(p =>
    {
        p.Enabled(true);
        p.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 });
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Selectable()
    .Groupable()
    .Scrollable() 
    .Filterable()    
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Country_Read", "Country")).PageSize(10)
     )
     .Events(events => events.Change("GridChange"))
     .ToolBar(toolbar =>
     {
        toolbar.Template(
            @<text>
                <div id="Toolbar">
                    <a id="Add" href="@Url.Action("Create", "Country")" title="Add New Record"></a>
                    <a id="Edit" title="Edit Selected Record"></a>
                    <a id="Delete" title="Delete Selected Record"></a>
                </div>
            </text>);
     })
      )
```

How do I refresh the column `CountryCodeLength` on 10-15 seconds regularly?
 I tried refreshing the complete Grid, but I have some popup to be open inside the same grid. So while refreshing complete grid on working with popup, the popup will be lost.
 Please tell me how I can refresh a single column?
Here is the code that I used to refresh the whole grid:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var refreshId = setInterval( function() {

                //GET YOUR GRID REFERENCE
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.dataSource.read();


    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var gridData  = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
var data      = gridData.at(0);//data at 0 Location
data.set("CountryCodeLength", 20);//set the value here
```

you can use a polling script to refresh the value

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyGrid  = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var selectedItem = MyGrid.dataItem(MyGrid.select());
selectedItem.set("CountryCodeLength", 10);
MyGrid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid=\"" + selectedItem.uid + "\"]").addClass("k-state-selected");
```